# Jest unexpected token error with NextJS-auth0

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, jestjs

I have a nextjs app that is using the nextjs-auth0 package. When I try to test a file using this import:

```
import { getSession } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
```

I get the following error:

```
Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

    Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

    By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.

    Here's what you can do:
     • If you are trying to use ECMAScript Modules, see https://jestjs.io/docs/ecmascript-modules for how to enable it.
     • If you are trying to use TypeScript, see https://jestjs.io/docs/getting-started#using-typescript
     • To have some of your "node_modules" files transformed, you can specify a custom "transformIgnorePatterns" in your config.
     • If you need a custom transformation specify a "transform" option in your config.
     • If you simply want to mock your non-JS modules (e.g. binary assets) you can stub them out with the "moduleNameMapper" config option.

    You'll find more details and examples of these config options in the docs:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration
    For information about custom transformations, see:
    https://jestjs.io/docs/code-transformation

    Details:

    /Users/someuser/app-project/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/web/index.js:1
    ({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import derive from './runtime/hkdf.js';

    SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  15 |
  16 | export default apiHandler(handler);
> 17 |
     | ^
  18 | export async function handler(
  19 |     req: NextApiRequest,
  20 |     res: NextApiResponse<User[] | ArityErrorResponse>
```

This error only happens if the tested file has an import related to `@auth0/nextjs-auth0` package.

I tried to ignore the package in question in the jest config (`@panva`) or the nextjs auth0 package itself, but no luck

```
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/@auth0/nextjs-auth0/']
```

I have tried to jest mock the package, but it's not letting me unfortunately. I suspect the `nextjs-auth0` package is using modern JS whilst jest is using `commonjs`, which this can be a conflict for jest.

Has anyone encountered this issue with this package and jest?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, I added this configuration inside the `moduleNameMapper` in the `jest.config` file

```
// jest.config
const customJestConfig = {
  // ...
  moduleNameMapper: {
    // ...
    "^@panva/hkdf": require.resolve("@panva/hkdf"),
    // ...
  },
  // ...
};
```

This resolves the Common JS module in `@panva` instead of jest using modern JS.

I got the solution from this post, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77435406/5062134